# HDMI port not recognized on Sony Vaio

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, hdmi, vaio, sony

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 64bit with a Sony VAIO VPC F11. It has an NVIDIA GeForce 310M video card, with the latest Nvidia drivers for the 64 bit linux, and a Windows partition with Win7 64bit.

NVIDIA driver version is NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-280.13

External monitor is Samsung SyncMaster P2770

If I boot into the Windows partition, the HDMI works as expected, with sound and video-- under linux, the HDMI port is not recognized at all, apparently, and provides no signal to the attached monitor. The nividia-settings tool does not recognize any monitor connected to the HDMI port.

Disper is installed and cannot recognize an attached external monitor.

Can anyone help me diagnose this issue and fix it if possible? The laptop has only the one HDMI port to connect any external monitor, so it I can't get this working I'm stuck using either the laptop screen or Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have your NVIDIA X.org drivers installed you should be able to run the config panel. There, when your external monitor is connected via HDMI port, you can detect displays and configure X server behaviour, eg. arrange displays in a way you need them to be.

Unfortunately, if you connect a TV to your VAIO you may not have any sound going to your TV, due to some problems with ALSA drivers.

Comment: @Matt-- thanks, however, even with the latest NVIDIA drivers the nvidia config tool does not recognize the attached input via HDMI. Oddly, it works if I use a DVI->HDMI adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to install a tool called disper. It's a command line tool focused on NVIDIA-drivers, because they don't support xrandr.

disper: [disper on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/disper)

Try `disper -l` to list all attached displays. If it is found, you can switch between your displays with disper.

Comment: @bdr529-- thanks for the tip, I did install disper and it cannot detect the HDMI monitor. I know the port works fine, since Windows has no problem using it. It's as if the port isn't even being enabled by Ubuntu.